# How to get all children records in MYSQL hierarchical data

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data, hierarchical

I have a table with the following columns

```
id   |    parent_customer_id
-----------------------------
1    |    0
2    |    0
3    |    1
4    |    2
5    |    4
6    |    4
```

I'd like a script that can return all the child ids of a certain customer.  For example

```
get_child_ids (1) = 1,3
get_child_ids(2) = 2,4,5,6
get_child_ids(3) = 3
get_child_ids(4) = 4,5,6
get_child_ids(5) = 5
get_child_ids(6) = 6
```

Some ids could go up to 10 levels deep.  I found a great solution to getting parent ids at https://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/ but I'm having trouble getting the children

Comment: What trouble? Data for id is different then other id in the sample data you shared.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is "write a recursive SQL query with CTE syntax" but this is not supported until MySQL 8.0.1.

Recursive CTE syntax is standard SQL, supported by all popular brands of SQL-compliant products now that MySQL is supporting it.

I did a presentation about the upcoming recursive query feature in MySQL at the Percona Live Conference in April 2017: [Recursive Query Throwdown in MySQL 8](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/recursive-query-throwdown).

```
WITH RECURSIVE MyCTE AS (
  SELECT id, parent_customer_id FROM MyTable WHERE id = ?
  UNION
  SELECT id, parent_customer_id FROM MyTable JOIN MyCTE 
    ON MyTable.parent_customer_id = MyCTE.id
)
SELECT * FROM MyCTE;
```

If you can't use MySQL 8.0.1 or later, you can use the clever solution at ExplainExtended, or you can store your hierarchical data in another way to support non-recursive queries.

I show a number of solutions in my presentation [Models for hierarchical data](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data), or in my answer to [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462).

I also wrote a chapter about this in my book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Answer (score 0):

You must check following article about *[Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)*

It's an excellent article that shows you a great technique on how to deal with hierarquical data with "infinite" depth.

**Word of Caution**: If **you're dealing with hierarquical data where child has an unique parent, this is a great solution for you**. But if **you're dealing with children that have more than one parent**, then you're dealing with graphs and for that reason, **MySQL it's not suitable for you**. You must **explore solutions as [Neo4J](https://neo4j.com/) instead**.